# How to valid generic cast in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

```
interface Command<I, O> {
    O process(I i);
}

interface Undo<I> {
    void undo(I i);
}


public class CommandRunner {
    public static <I, O> O process(Command<I, O> command, I request) {
        O result = null;

        try {
            result = command.process(request);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            if (command instanceof Undo) {
                ((Undo<I>) command).undo(request); // <-- unchecked cast
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

How can I avoid unchecked cast warning?

Comment: Do you have the same class implementing both `Command` and `Undo`? If so, why not make a third interface that extends both?

Answer (score 0):

1) If `Undo` is a *specialized* `Command`, have `Undo` extend `Command`:-

```
interface Undo<I> extends Command {...}
```

2) Else, you can create a third interface:-

```
interface ReversibleCommand extends Command, Undo {...}
```

and switch to `if (command instanceof ReversibleCommand) {...}`

Comment: All class does not implement undo.
"class SomeClass implements Command<Request, Response>, Undo<Requset> {...}"
"class OtherClass implements Command<Request, Response> {...}"

Thus only class implements undo, execute undo method on exception.

Comment: If you are going with the first option, you need to change classes implementing both `Command` and `Undo` to implement only `Undo` now. If going with second option, change classes implementing both `Command` and `Undo` to implement `ReversibleCommand` now.